# Is there a way to extract out just the Carrier signal from an AM signal?

Tags: demodulation

I have a AM signal with 13.56MHz carrier and 125KHz data signal. I was wondering if there is a way to extract out just the pure carrier signal out of this AM signal. I was thinking about passing it through a high pass filter, instead of a low pass filter, as used for its demodulation. But I am not sure if this will work.

Comment: Erm... Why? It's just a sine wave. You can generate it yourself.

Comment: to put what Eugene said a bit more specifically: *Carrier Recovery* is a very mature field, but what you need to do depends on what you need to achieve. You tell us nothing about why you want that carrier. Also, if you say "data signal", you probably mean ASK, not AM, right? Also, no, just a filter will not work.

Comment: **AM signal** might mean 100% modulation by the 125 kHz data. Often called OOK (on-off-keying). In that case, one of your symbol periods contains no carrier at all - and that's very hard to extract. Less than 100% modulation allows PLL carrier recovery. But phase locking requires some time to settle.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a Phase Locked Loop (PLL) if your unsure of the carrier frequency. The loop detects phase differences between a sine wave an incoming signal then adjusts its frequency to make the phase difference go to zero.

If you know your carrier frequency and it's fixed a waveform generator will work, or oscillator circuit to generate the frequency.

[image]
Source: https://www.radio-electronics.com/info/rf-technology-design/pll-synthesizers/phase-locked-loop-tutorial.php

Answer (score 2):

A narrow crystal filter could do a pretty good job here, as long as the bandwidth is << 125 kHz.  That assuming the carrier is accurate enough.  Of course if the carrier is exactly known there is no reason to "extract it".

Alternately, feed the signal into a comparator to generate a square wave, then use a PLL to make a sine wave at the same frequency.

Probably there are other solutions, but ultimately they depend on what your actual goal is.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this can be derived with high gain after band pass filtering with a limiter.   The problem is knowing what specs to error tolerance to frequency error or phase noise or amplitude variations or interference from stronger adjacent channels .

These are problems solved by superhet, and specifications for image rejection. But your requirements are not so clear so the other answers may be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes when you have full double sideband suppressed carrier (full amplitude modulation). The carrier signal reverses phase and is, in effect suppressed. The composite waveform contains only sidebands and no measure of actual carrier and it can't be detected with a simple filter or simple PLL circuit. The waveform might look something like this: -

[image]

[Picture source](https://archive.cnx.org/contents/b5be5e4c-4ab8-4765-a3d3-534ee2ee2ff3@1/the-phase-reversal-in-dsb-sc). You should be able to see that the carrier reverses phase every 10 seconds (this is just a slow timebase and in reality happens much faster) making carrier frequency extraction more difficult.

One method that can be implemented is to mathematically square the composite waveform (using a standard RF mixer for instance) and what results is a carrier signal that is twice the frequency but, importantly, it doesn't have phase reversals: -

[image]

This then means you can demodulate and/or extract the carrier using this method: -

[image]

Picture taken from [AM-DSB-CS coherent demodulators with carrier recovery](http://aaronscher.com/wireless_system_simulations/DSB_CS_1.html).